# Mist Wallet Stuck on "Connected to Node"

Tags: cryptography

It got about 80% of the way through the blockchain download, then it just stopped and went to "finding peers" So I closed the wallet, restarted the PC, and now it just gets stuck on "connected to node". I have since moved the lightchaindata folder out, and am currently re-downloading. I imagine the same thing will happen again. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just going through similar crap myself. Here's the answer I arrived at:

1. Close the Ethereum Wallet
2. Run `geth` in a terminal/command prompt (located at `~/Library/Application\ Support/Ethereum\ Wallet/binaries/Geth/unpacked/geth` on OSX or `%AppData%\Ethereum Wallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked\geth` on Windows)
3. Open a second terminal/command prompt and run `geth attach` (adding path to geth if required)
4. Wait a few seconds then execute `eth.syncing` in the geth console - pay attention to the numbers.
5. Give it a few more seconds and re-run- check the sync is incrementing.
6. If it is, open Ethereum Wallet and keep an eye on the first geth terminal/command prompt window for any errors. Ethereum Wallet will use that geth instance as it's local node.

Comment: I tried again using the ethereum wallet installer, and it now gets stuck at the last 200 blocks. I still tried your fix, but as soon as I type in 
"%APPDATA%\Ethereum Wallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked\geth.exe" it starts the blockchain syncing. And it just keeps saying syncing headers etc.